# Flink OOM error processing of large sized records

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have a Flink application which has Kafka topics as source and S3 bucket as a FileSinknk. The aim of the pipeline is to read data from Kafka Topics and store it in parquet files for analytics.

The records in Kafka are Avro serialized are limited to a max size of 5 MB. If the avro serialized object size is >5 MB, the producer uploads the serialized avro object to a large-messages-s3-bucket and then publishes a reference record from where the consumers can get the actual avro data (the object path from the large-messages-S3-bucket).

The size of avro objects can go upto 2-3 GBs. In our KafkaSource, we use a customized deserializer to convert the avro record into a GenericRecord. The FileSink code forms the path from the GenericRecord using a couple of fields and then Sinks into a S3-Bucket.

If it is a large message (>5MB), the deserializer code fetches the actual avro record from the large-messages-S3-bucket by making an API call and then follows the same process. The pipeline works well but when avro record size reaches the range of 1 GB, the task manager's heap usage goes very high.

Even with 16-17 GB assigned heap memory, the task manager fails with a single 1.4 GB avro record.

I tried using VisualVM to analyse the memory usage. The following is the snapshot with 1 single 800 MB record processed.

[image]

If I send the same record multiple times, the memory keeps on increasing and the task manager crashes with OOM error. This is the output with an ~10 GB heap with the same 800 MB record sent 3 times one after the other.

[image]

Is this purely a lack of enough heap memory problem? How can I further debug this issue? Why is a 800 MB avro taking almost 6 GB of memory to process. Why is that memory not getting freed up once it is processed?

There is a managed memory component in Flink for storing state. Can that be somehow utilized in this scenario?

Edit - Flink version 1.15.2

Comment: Files in disk are optimized for that type of storage and usually don't weight the same in memory. The memory will be freed up once the GC runs. I don't know the contents of your files but maybe you can look into String deduplication to improve heap usage?

Comment: What's the parallelism of the job, per TM? And do you have any functions between your source and sink (what's the job topology)?